# Switch Redshift WLM parameter group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have the scenario, during the business hours extreme reporting tasks on Redshift (say database queries, tableau extracts, tableau live connections etc) and in the night the ETL tasks start

Is there any way to switch between the WLM parameter groups on a timely basis, so that during business hours I can have the Reporting WLM parameter group and at night I can have the ETL parameter group?

Comment: I don't think you could do it. Here is the reference that clearly says, you can't do. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-wlm-dynamic-properties.html

Comment: So it seems I can change the Dynamic values instead of changing the parameter groups

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this easily with the AWS CLI. The following example comes from our documentation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/workload-mgmt-config.html#Configuring-the-wlm-json-configuration-Parameter

You will need to schedule an external tool to run this at the desired times. Consider AWS Lambda for this as it has the ability to schedule executions. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html

Example:

```
aws redshift modify-cluster-parameter-group 
--parameter-group-name example-parameter-group 
--parameters
'[
   {
      "ParameterName":"wlm_json_configuration",
      "ParameterValue":"[
         {
            "query_group":["report"],
            "query_group_wild_card":1,
            "query_concurrency":4,
            "max_execution_time":20000,
            "memory_percent_to_use":25
         },
         {
            "user_group":["admin","dba"],
            "user_group_wild_card":0,
            "query_concurrency":5,
            "memory_percent_to_use":40
         },
         {
            "query_concurrency":5,
            "memory_percent_to_use":35
         },
         {
            "short_query_queue": true,
            "max_execution_time": 0
        }
      ]",
      "ApplyType":"dynamic"
   }
]'
```